# preg_quote() bug or strange behavior?

Tags: php, regex

I used preg_quote() to escape some special characters. But in the test below, there is something I can't understand.

Why 'date:1111aaa' doesn't match ???

```
<?php
$PregArray = ['date:1111aaa', ':222aaa', '@odia tvled'];


$array['attract (step-date:1111aaa)'] = 'OK';
$array['type (step-date:222aaa)'] = 'OK';
$array['@odia tvled'] = 'OK';


foreach ($PregArray as $key_1 => $val_1) {
    echo "\n--------------";
    foreach ($array as $key_2 => $val_2) {
        if (preg_match("~$val_1~", preg_quote($key_2))) {
            echo "\nOK => $val_1 - ".preg_quote($key_2);
            break;
            }
        else {
            echo "\nNOK !!! => $val_1 - ".preg_quote($key_2);
            }
        }
    }
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ef36e2b010ac1f4f0eaf08881004892bd0cd9c4

Comment: You need `preg_quote()` to escape special characters so they can be used as literals in pattern, not in the string that's matched.

Comment: @shudder I'm OK with you. I tried to use `preg_quote()` in this way. Do you mean I didn't ?

Comment: Nothig in your question implies that you did, What I wrote mean that you need this: `preg_match('~' . preg_quote($val_1) . '~', $key_2)`

Comment: @shudder OK I see now... Ouuups. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `preg_quote` in the wrong place, it is intended for escaping characters in the pattern, not the test string (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)). Change your code to this and it works fine:

```
foreach ($PregArray as $key_1 => $val_1) {
    echo "\n--------------";
    foreach ($array as $key_2 => $val_2) {
        if (preg_match('~' . preg_quote($val_1) . '~', $key_2)) {
            echo "\nOK => $val_1 - $key_2";
            break;
            }
        else {
            echo "\nNOK !!! => $val_1 - $key_2";
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
--------------
OK => date:1111aaa - attract (step-date:1111aaa)
--------------
NOK !!! => :222aaa - attract (step-date:1111aaa)
OK => :222aaa - type (step-date:222aaa)
--------------
NOK !!! => @odia tvled - attract (step-date:1111aaa)
NOK !!! => @odia tvled - type (step-date:222aaa)
OK => @odia tvled - @odia tvled
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TG09P)